# PHP - Convert Array of Days into Array of Weeks if Greater Than 7 Days

Tags: php, arrays

Basically, the website allows the user to select a date range and then will display data pulled from that range.  It needs to be built do that if the date range is 7 days or less it shows daily information, or weekly information if more than 7 days. The date range is unlimited (ie, they could select 74 days, which should return ten 7 day weeks, and one 4 day week). The data is pulled as:

```
[sales] => Array
    (
        [2014-02-02] => Array
            (
                [key1] => 1
                [key2] => 2
                [key3] => 3
            )

        [2014-02-03] => Array
            (
                [key1] => 4
                [key2] => 5
                [key3] => 6
            )

        [2014-02-04] => Array
            (
                [key1] => 7
                [key2] => 8
                [key3] => 9
            )

        [2014-02-05] => Array
            (
                [key1] => 9
                [key2] => 8
                [key3] => 7
            )

        [2014-02-06] => Array
            (
                [key1] => 6
                [key2] => 5
                [key3] => 4
            )

        [2014-02-07] => Array
            (
                [key1] => 3
                [key2] => 2
                [key3] => 1
            )

        [2014-02-08] => Array
            (
                [key1] => 1
                [key2] => 2
                [key3] => 3
            )

        [2014-02-09] => Array
            (
                [key1] => 4
                [key2] => 5
                [key3] => 6
            )
    )
```

And needs to be converted to something like (with anything over the 7 day range combined into the last array):

```
[sales] => Array
    (
        [2014-02-02 - 2014-02-08] => Array
            (
                [key1] => 31
                [key2] => 32
                [key3] => 33
            )

        [2014-02-09 - 2014-02-09] => Array
            (
                [key1] => 4
                [key2] => 5
                [key3] => 6
            )
    )
```

EDIT:
I understand that it will be in some sort of loop, but can't figure out the logic to get the keys and values to combine into groups of 7.

```
if(count($array['sales']) > 7){
    //do something here
}
```

Comment: This can be solved with a simple loop

Answer (score 0):

It's better when you use a unix timestamp as the date.

```
if(($time1+(3600*24*7))>$time2)
{
The difference is larger than 7 days
}
```